# How to create a Button that opens the previous excel sheet in VB.NET?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to create a Button that opens the previously opened excel sheet.What would be your Idea?

There is a code in VBA: `Sheet(ActiveSheet.previos.Activate).select`

I tried to translate this into vb.NET but it did not worked.

```
Dim ActiveWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet=

Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Activeworkbook.Worksheet(ActiveWorkSheet.Previous).select()
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answer 1) You can try the following as it will store the last page into your workbook. Make sure to remove the msgbox's when you have this operating how you would like it to. I put the following code in the `ThisWorkBook` object in Excel.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim docProp As DocumentProperty
    Dim strSheet As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        If .CustomDocumentProperties.Count > 0 Then
            For Each docProp In .CustomDocumentProperties
                If LCase(Trim(docProp.Name)) = "previoussheet" Then
                    strSheet = .ActiveSheet.Name
                    docProp.Value = strSheet

                    MsgBox "Worksheet (" & strSheet & ") has been saved."

                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Else
            .CustomDocumentProperties.Add "PreviousSheet", False, msoPropertyTypeString, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim wrk As Workbook
  Dim docProp As DocumentProperty
  Dim strSheet As String

  Set wrk = ThisWorkbook

  If wrk.CustomDocumentProperties.Count > 0 Then
      For Each docProp In wrk.CustomDocumentProperties
          If LCase(Trim(docProp.Name)) = "previoussheet" Then
              strSheet = docProp.Value
              wrk.Worksheets(strSheet).Select
              MsgBox "Worksheet " & strSheet & " has been selected."
              Exit For
          End If
      Next
  End If

  Set wrk = Nothing
End Sub
```

(Answer 2) You can try doing this. However, you will need to open the workbook using the object below and then hold that variable (objExcel) in memory until you are done with it. The set keyword is required by vba, but if you are doing this in vb.net then, you can remove the set keywords and then you can set the object equal to nothing once you are done with it. Here is the code:

```
    Public objExcel As Object
    Dim strSheet as string
    Dim intSheet as integer

    Public Sub GetPrevSheet()
        Dim intI as integer

        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        strSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
        'Find the sheet with the same name as the active sheet
        for intI = 1 to objExcel.Activeworkbook.Worksheets.count
            if lcase(trim(strsheet)) = _
               lcase(trim(objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(inti).name)) then
                intSheet = intI
                exit for
            End if
        next intI

        'Go back 1 and then select it.
        if intSheet > 1 then intSheet = intSheet - 1

        objExcel.Activeworkbook.Worksheets(intSheet).select

        Set objExcel = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: the Problem is everytime i use this Kind of Code:  "...ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Previous.Select" i get an error saying : System.NullReferenceException

Comment: The main Idea is to create a back button that brings me back to the previous opened sheet may you have a better idea, thx for the answer!